# pthread_create buffer size. Not enough?

Tags: c++, pthreads, buffer

I'm trying to create a thread with `pthread_create` function. The call is something like that:
`res pthread_create(&threadID, &atributte, function, argument)`

`res` value is always `0` which means that pthread_create launch the thread right.
The problem, I think, is in the last parameter (argument). It is a too loooooong string and I think this is crashing my program because if I try with a shorter string It's all correct and ends properly.

I was wondering if `pthread_create` creates a thread with a certain amount of memory and If any of you know that amount.

PD: My log doesn't show anything, I put a `cout` at the first line of `function` but is never readed because my program crashes before it happens.

Thank you all!

Edit: Rest of the code, how i create the thread.

```
    void znkModulePlugin::createMainProcess(void* mod){
znkModulePlugin* module = static_cast<znkModulePlugin*>(mod);
try{
    int res = 0;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    res = pthread_create(&threadID, &attr, znkModulePlugin::launchThread, module); 
}catch(exception e){
    stringstream log_msg;
    log_msg << " CRIT znkModulePlugin::createMainProcess() -> Critical Error: " << e.what() << ". Reseting Node.";
    logData(log_msg.str());
}
```

}

Comment: Are you making sure the string that `argument` points to isn't destroyed before the thread accesses it? `pthread_create` won't allocate memory for it itself; it just passes on the pointer you give it.

Comment: How do you create `argument`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, you should make that the answer - this is most likely the case.

Comment: Yes, I can type the string just before launch `pthread_create` and is complete!
If the string is destroyed before i call it this will happen with my shorter strings.

Comment: @Urien: Seriously, post more code. Show how you create `argument`.

Comment: @Urien: OK, could you show us the code that creates the string and passes it to `pthread_create()`? Without that, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure is too complicated, is a `foo` class with plenty of functions and other classes, one of them is something like `getOMGString()` which returns my string.

Comment: Ok ok, but I think this will be more complicated, hold a sec.

Comment: @Urien: well could you find the lines of code that call `getOMGString()` and pass the result to `pthread_create()`? Seriously, we can't guess what's wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: Well, if the string is returned from a function, hopefully that means it is allocated on the heap or in data. But it still helps if we can see it.

Comment: How is `mod` defined? Is it a class member, a global variable, or a local variable?

Comment: well, I posted the header of the function that I forgot.

Comment: I can access to my string with `module->getOMGString()`

Comment: When you use C++, why aren't you using `boost::thread`, C++11 `std::thread` or any other threading library at a proper abstraction level?

Comment: Because in a heavy project that use std libraries. Boost library could have helped in so many forms but I can not use it :(

Answer (score 1):

Follow this pattern to avoid problems:

1) Allocate a `new` object/struct holding the information the new thread needs.

2) Call `pthread_create` passing it a pointer to the new object.

3) When the thread is done accessing the information, `delete` the object/struct.

If you pass a thread a pointer to something, you must make sure that pointer remains valid (and its contents unmodified unless synchronized) until the new thread is done with it.